What is this stone from Miyagase dam?
Please some one help to identify the stone from presumably Miyagase dam.
What is it for? Is it really the 30 mil years old? Is there some additional info about it?
Sorry in advance for incorrect topic, but I absolutely stuck and frustrated to understand the meaning behind it and don't know where to search.
It was bought in Kazakhstan in second hand store. Why the stone there I don't know. Description upon the stone says that this stone is taken from 150 m deep and said serve to bring luck.
A rough translation via Google:

This stone is a talisman stone that will increase your score (sacred stone).This stone was excavated with a diamond cutter to a depth of 150 to 200 meters from the bottom of Miyagase Dam in order to create a water stop wall (curtain wall) that will challenge the huge water pressure of the dam. It is the main stone (sacred stone) 30 million years ago. Please use it as a talisman stone to improve your grades (sacred stone). Operator: Ministry of Construction Miyagase Dam Construction Office Producer: Miyagase Dam Area Promotion Foundation. courtesy of justcal and google translate

I think this is some sort of a merchandise from the dam museum and money from sold items goes to dam fond. But that's just wild guess.
Is it possible to know when exactly the souvenir was sold? It seems that the museum is not selling these things anymore


Please add more information about the stone such as what the text says, where it was acquired, etc. Although I'm not sure that historical methods can really help you here.

The Dam in question appears to be of typical steel-reinforced concrete construction, and was built in the 20th century. That means that it wasn't built of stone, so no stone you have could literally be from the Dam. I suppose it could be a stone from nearby, and its not weird (I don't think?) for random stones to be millions of years old. However, this isn't EarthSciences.SE, so don't quote me on that last bit.

Would it be possible to have a full translation of the text added to the question?

So its a souvenir from the constructions drilling process being sold as a lucky rock.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not a history question
